# Append Files in Unix - Cat doesn't work

Tags: unix, datastage

I am trying to append files with a unix command in datastage and its not working.

Unix commands does work.

For examples if there are 5 files in a directory like

/a/file1.txt /a/file2.txt /a/file3.txt /a/file4.txt /a/file5.txt

Second files is not appending in output. I did interchanged files and second file is not in output.

Do you know how files can be appended using AWK or SED, I want to give it a try

Comment: What exactly did you run? `cat`ing multiple files should just output them one after the other.

Comment: I did cat /a/file1.txt /a/file2.txt /a/file3.txt /a/file4.txt /a/file5.txt > /a/file.txt it is not appending the file2.txt so I am looking for an awk or sed and see if that works

Comment: ```cat``` followed by the list of files should work OK. Could it be that the paths are incorrect (e.g. absolute vs. relative paths or something similar)?

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

```
find . -type f | xargs cat | tee outputfile.txt
```

Explanation:

- `find` will list the files (the parameters exclude the directories)
- `xargs cat` will display the content of each file
- `tee` will show the output in the console and write it to the outputfile as well.

Comment: I had to put the output somewhere else because it read the outputfile and combined it in.  Nothing I couldn't handle thanks